# React.js useContext and useReducer not working

Tags: reactjs

React.js useContext and useReducer not working

```
const initialState = {
  isSidebarOpen: false,
  featuredData: [],
};
```

State initilized.

```
const featuredProducts = () => {
    const featuredProduct = productsData;
    dispatch({ type: FEATURED_PRODUCTS, payload: featuredProduct });
  };
```

productsData - Data from an array.

```
if (action.type === FEATURED_PRODUCTS) {
    const featuredData = action.payload.map((data) => {
      return data.title;
    });
    return {
      ...state,
      featuredProduct: action.payload,
      featuredData,
    };
  }

 const { featuredData } = useProductsContext();
  console.log(featuredData);
```

console log is undefined

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Problem solved thanks